# Sending error with Spring's HandlerInterceptor results in 406 (Not Acceptable) response

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm trying to use Spring's `HandlerInterceptorAdapter` to handle the case when the application is scheduled for Maintenance for the following rest-endpoint: `/api/authentication`

So I created an interceptor by extending `HandlerInterceptorAdapter`:

```
public class MigrationStateInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
        if(someLogic) {
            return true
        }

        response.reset();
        response.sendError(HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE.value());
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public void postHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, ModelAndView modelAndView) throws Exception {}

    @Override
    public void afterCompletion(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler, Exception ex) throws Exception {}
}
```

And then I added it to my `InterceptorRegistry`:

```
@Override
public void addInterceptors(InterceptorRegistry registry) {
    registry.addInterceptor(new MigrationStateInterceptor()).addPathPatterns("/api/authentication");
}
```

The problem is that instead of receiving a `503 (Service Unavailable)` error on client-side, I receive `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 406 (Not Acceptable)`

As it can be seen in the code snippet, I tried reseting the response, but with no result.
I also tried modifying the `Accept` and `Content-Type` headers but with no luck:

```
response.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE);
response.addHeader("Accept", "text/plain");
```

Any idea why this occurs and how it can be avoided?

**NOTE**: I'm using Angular on client-side. From what I see `HttpServletResponse#sendError` sets the content type to `text/html`, leaving cookies and other headers unmodified. Could this be a problem?

**EDIT**:
I even tried throwing an exception instead of using `HttpServletResponse#sendError`, and handle that separately, but the end result was the same.

E.g.:

```
@Override
public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) throws Exception {
    if (some logic) {
        return true;
    }
    throw new MigrationStateException("Migration process is disabled");
}

 @ExceptionHandler(MigrationStateException.class)
public ResponseEntity<String> migrationStateError(MigrationStateException e) {
    return new ResponseEntity<>(e.getMessage(), HttpStatus.SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE);
}
```

Comment: Can you get a debugger to break within that preHandle?

Comment: Yes, I can. What are you interested in finding out?

Comment: Does your client really expect `text/plain`? That would be quite unusual. `sendError` doesn't simply set the content type, it sends an error page. You want to send your own response. Exception handlers only apply to controllers.

Comment: @zeroflagL The exception handler caught the exception, even if it wasn't in the controller. Are there issues with the response returned from a non-controller environment?

Regarding what I'm expecting on client side, I can easily change, but something happens on server side that translates the 503 to 406. At least, this is what I observed. Do you have any suggestions regarding this?

Thanks!

Comment: 406 means that the client expects something the server doesn't deliver. It's important to know what media type the client expects. I assume that the server treats `ResponseEntity<String>` as `text/plain` and the client expects `application/json`. Try to return a `Map` .

Answer (score 0):

I believe the problem is the request you're mapping to `/api/authenticate` is either not expecting `text/html`, or your sending the wrong type of request (i.e. `GET` instead of a `POST`, etc.)

You stated that angular is sending `text/html`, given the usual defaults associated with an authenticate endpoint, it's probably expecting `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` data.  Therefore, Spring is intercepting a `Content-Type` it doesn't have mapped and 406'ing.

Comment: Hi @dardo, Spring is setting the content type to `text/html`, not angular. More exactly the `HttpServletResponse#sendError` method. I tried bypassing that by throwing the exception instead and send the response from an exception handler, but with no success. The request is alright, the problem is with the response sent from Spring.

Comment: That's because you're intercepting it AFTER spring receives the request. The `text/html` in this case is the error page itself, not the response you're expecting.